# how to retrieve modified process variable in jbpm workbench

Tags: drools, jbpm, kie

I'm trying to invoke a jbpm process with a custom object process variable via remote client against kie server.
The process does some updates on the process variable which I need to retrieve back.
What's the best way to retrieve the modified process variable?
Appreciate any examples along with answer. 
[6.5.0 final]

Comment: I'm using docker image for jbpm workbench. Invoking the process from eclipse using remote client. I enabled persistence on the process variable. Not sure where the data is stored.

Answer (score 1):

If process instance is completed then you can use below REST API's to get process variable info

```
[GET]   http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/queries/processes/instances/{ProcessInstanceID}/variables/instances 

[GET]   http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/queries/processes/instances/{ProcessInstanceID}?withVars=true
```

If process instance is active then you can use below REST API:

```
http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/{containerId}/processes/instances/{ProcessInstanceId}/variables
```

Comment: Thanks. I got the variable out. But I ran some updates on the variable inside the process which is not returned. The REST call only gives the initial state of the variable. It seems, we should enable persistence for the variable. If yes, what's the best way in docker container. I enabled persistence for the variable, not sure where to find the data in docker.

Comment: Also, if I want to use mysql as the data source for persistence how do I configure it.

Comment: Bydefault process variable values are persisted into VariableInstsanceLog table. In the response of the above REST API you should be able to see old value and new value.